# How to Login to a website in Android and retrieve data from it?

Tags: java, android, https

now i want to make an android app that would allow me to log in, then retrieve some information , and then showing it on the app. 
Please help me with the concept to use.
Thank you :) :)

Comment: This is too broad.

Comment: `please provide the code nd help me` **NO**. This is not how this site works.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is only possible if the site provides android sdk to login and returns information.